# How to create one DataFrame using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Recently I am struggling to learn how to create DataFrames using Pandas being guided by Pandas' documentation. The main problems that I was having were related to the parameters of the *DataFrame* function. The attributes *columns* and *index*. I was using one object containing the data and was trying to create one DataFrame using that data.

The code that I am working on and having errors is this:

```
data = [["Orange", "Watermelon", "Banana", "Apple"], [10, 30, 23, 56]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1], columns=data[0])
print(df)
```

It does not work for me, and if I remove the *columns* parameter it works. What can be done to solve it?

Comment: You probably meant `pd.DataFrame(data=[data[1]], columns=data[0])`. `data=` is looking for a 2d list containing all the rows. In your case you have 1 row, so the outer list has 1 element with your 4 cells of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone who has experience with DataFrame, the problem is clear and easy to find out, but for who is starting it can be very frustrating to have to deal with problems like that.

The problem with the DataFrame is that pandas will not be able to assign 4 data values as 4 columns if you do not guide pandas to do so. What I was trying to do was to create one DataFrame of 4 lines and 1 column (4,1) using 4 data values and 4 column names (4,4). For the code work, you can use the columns values as index and then transpose your DataFrame. What `transpose()` does is simply transform the lines of the DataFrame into columns.

```
data = [["Orange", "Watermelon", "Banana", "Apple"], [10, 30, 23, 56]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1], index=data[0]).transpose()
print(df)

   Orange  Watermelon  Banana  Apple
0      10          30      23     56
```

The first way will work just if you have enough data to create one 4x4 DataFrame, for example:

```
data = [["Orange", "Watermelon", "Banana", "Apple"], [
    [10, 30, 23, 56], [18, 44, 12, 73], [2, 24, 88, 10], [5, 71, 35, 62]]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1], columns=data[0])
print(df)

   Orange  Watermelon  Banana  Apple
0      10          30      23     56
1      18          44      12     73
2       2          24      88     10
3       5          71      35     62
```

**EDIT**

As @Mayank said, it can be simplified by:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[data[1]], columns=data[0]) 

   Orange  Watermelon  Banana  Apple
0      10          30      23     56
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
In [1426]: df = pd.DataFrame(data=[data[1]], columns=data[0])

In [1427]: df
Out[1427]: 
   Orange  Watermelon  Banana  Apple
0      10          30      23     56
```